# NSMutableArray is not mutable anymore after passing it to another viewController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, nsmutablearray

I'm using NavigationController and in the MasterViewController I have a NSMutableArray called _emails, when I prepareForSegue I do this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SelectContactViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.delegate = self;
    vc.emails = _emails;
}
```

in SelectContactViewController _emails is correctly filled with datas from MasterViewController _emails property, But it is no more Mutable! I can't add/remove object. Here is definition of _emails in SelectContactsViewController:

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

@protocol MyViewDelegate;

@interface SelectContactViewController : UITableViewController {
    id<MyViewDelegate> delegate;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* emails;
```

and definition of _emails in MasterViewController:

```
@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_emails;
}
```

How can I pass a MutableArray to another view and still be a MutableArray??

Comment: Do you happen to alloc an NSArray instead of an NSMutableArray?

Comment: you can try this vc.emails = [_emails mutableCopy];

Comment: Though there is a way to turn NSMutableArray into NSArray, it's only accessible from the innards of the Cocoa library.  Mere mortals cannot cause such a transformation to occur.

Comment: Describe what makes you think the array is no longer mutable.  What are the symptoms?  And how do you know the array was mutable in the first place.  (Declarations don't count -- you can easily have a sheep in wolf's clothing.)

Comment: I don't know if the array was Mutable at the first place or not, the declaration was Mutable. But when I addObject or RemoveObject from _emails array, code crashes. 
I used @viperking method, and everything is good!

Comment: @HotLicks You can easily turn an instance of `NSMutableArray` into `NSArray` by calling `-copy`.

Comment: It seems I used this line of code that converted the MutableArray to a NSArray at the first place
    _emails   = [combined valueForKey:@"email"];

Comment: @sbooth - That's not changing an object, it's creating a new one.

Comment: @HotLicks You're right, I misunderstood the intent of your original comment

Comment: @Hadu - That line converted nothing.  The array never was mutable in the first place.  The type of pointer has no effect on the object.  (If this is coming from JSON, many JSON parsers have a setting that will return all mutable objects, in case you need them.)

Comment: @HotLicks the object was Mutable at the first place, I change the line to 

_emails = [[combined valueForKey:@"email"] mutableCopy];

and everything is good!

Comment: @Hadu - No, if that fixes it the object was not mutable in the first place.  That operation makes (duh!) a copy of the original object, and that copy is mutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the below lines

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SelectContactViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.delegate = self;
    vc.emails = _emails;
}
```

To the below lines

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SelectContactViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.delegate = self;
    vc.emails = [_emails mutableCopy];
}
```

Comment: One more note, if you want to "pass" you shouldn't use mutableCopy because when you use mutableCopy you get the newly allocated array of items. If you need the changes in the secondviewcontroller when you return back to firstviewcontroller, you will not be able to retrieve it.

Comment: What @kkocabiyik says is very important.  If you need a mutable version of the array it's presumably so you can change it and later access the changes.  But any changes made in a copy will not be reflected back to the original, kind of negating any advantage of having a mutable copy in the first place.

Comment: I totally agree with it :)